# Entry point could not be located in dynamic library libstdc++-6.dll

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, g++, freeglut

Ok, so I've built a C++ application that uses some external libraries.

I've built it with cmake and g++, both complete compilation without an error.

After compilation, I open my built application and out comes the error.

```
The procedure entry point _ZNKSt7_cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcESaIcEE5c_strEv could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll.
```

Now I'm wondering... Is there any way to compile it to be static? Do I need to get a newer version of libstdc++-6.dll?

my current code for compilation is

```
g++ main.cpp -o application.exe -L"C:/MinGW/lib/" -lopengl32 -lfreeglut -lDevIL -lILU -lILUT -I"C:/MinGW/include"
```

Comment: I suspect you have an older version of `libstdc++-6.dll`
 in your path somewhere and that is being used instead of the newer one.

Comment: I think I solved it now, the problem was that it wasn't being compiled statically. Now I'm getting a new error and will probably make a new question about that.